# How to get string after first space in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have MS Excel file with 8k products code. For example:

```
SOR 309704 or
LEW 2992 6005BK
```

I need a formula which cut this string to first space.

```
SOR 309704 to 309704
LEW 2992 6005BK to 2992 6005BK
```

Can You help me with this problem ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`=FIND(" ",A1)` will give you the position of the first space character. Then you can take everything on the right-hand side using the `right()` function:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND(" ", A1))
```